# How to create a formula field that will calculate the all the sum of other fields

Tags: community

I have created fields for January to December. I am trying to create a formula field that will show in the report the Jan - Dec in 2014 and Jan - Dec 2015

Answer (score 0):

I assume the following: You've added 12 fields in an object. Each field contains a number. Your intention is to have a report, which shows the sum (or an other formular, e.g. average) of those 12 fields.

Therefore you'll need another field. In the classic UI: *your object* -> Fields -> Custom Fields & Relationships -> New -> Formular -> choose label, select Number -> in the formular editor sum up the fields with the formular you need (in your case similar to `Jan + Feb + Mar + Apr + May + Jun + Jul + Aug + Sep + Oct + Nov + Dez`). This new field can then be added to your report in the report builder.

You can only summarize or group records (vertically), not fields (horizontally), in the report builder.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to create for separate months not the sum of all months.

Comment: Sorry, could you try to rephrase what your intention is? Maybe with an actual example. Initially you've wrote, that you want to show "Jan - Dec in 2014", which is a sum for me.